# How do I make the video AUTOPLAY inside Iframe?

Tags: video, iframe

I would like to ask is there a way to play an Auto video inside an Iframe (the frame I have no control over its content) and this is the video code

`<iframe src="https://vidshar.org/embed-xa1jv200fnl0.html?Key=RRZriqQpY8oMdojcT0RQEA&amp;Expires=1671368582?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" ></iframe>`

I hope my question is clear

Answer (score 0):

In order to autoplay a video, the iframe needs to include `?autoplay=1` in the src property and `allow=autoplay` property as well.

```html
<iframe src="https://vidshar.org/embed-xa1jv200fnl0.html?Key=RRZriqQpY8oMdojcT0RQEA&amp;Expires=1671368582?autoplay=1" 
        allow="autoplay"
        frameborder="0"
        allowfullscreen=""
        sandbox="allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts">
</iframe>
```

`allow="autoplay"` is missing, I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I tried all these methods and they did not work. I think the solution is in JavaScript or JQuery

Comment: I agree with @ahmedmundher
same here
nothing helps